conditionally replacing values of a series of variables using a loop
I am converting extensive stata code to R.
In stata, if I have a series of variables such as var1, var2, var3, etc., and I want to change (recode) a specific value if it appears in any of the variables, I can do that using the statement
recode var*(9999 = -9). In this case, I want to change all 9999's in the variable series to NA.
HERE IS THE CODE I TRIED
data = data.frame(var1=c(5, 56, 9999, 56, 78, 51),
              var2=c( 9999, 56, 43, 56, 78, 9999),
              var3=c(5, 34, 56, 78, 76, 79))
 varlist=gsub(" ","",paste("data$var",1:3,sep=""))
 varlist
 summary(data$var2)
 for (v in varlist){
   v[v=="9999"] = NA
 }
summary(data$var2)
data$var2[data$var2==9999] = NA
summary(data$var2)

LOOP DIDN'T WORK, SINGLE ASSIGNMENT (data$var2[data$var2==9999] = NA) DID AS SHOWN BY WHAT THE THREE summary(data$var2) SHOW:
Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.
43      56      67    3372    7519    9999
Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.
43      56      67    3372    7519    9999
Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's
43.00   52.75   56.00   58.25   61.50   78.00       2
THE CONTENTS OF VARLIST IS
[1] "data$var1" "data$var2" "data$var3"
I ALSO TRIED THE FOLLOWING LOOP BASED ON WHAT I FOUND ON STACKOVERFLOW (https://forum.posit.co/t/using-variables-names-in-loops/128653/2):
for (i in 1:3) {
  variable = paste0("data$var", i)
  variable[variable==9999] = NA
}

IT ALSO DIDN'T WORK.
CLEARLY I'M MISSING SOMETHING HERE.

Welcome to SO, but you don't make friends by shouting.  In the tidyverse, somethings simliar to mutate(across(starts_with("var"), \(x) ifelse(x == 9999, NA, x)) should give you what you want.

Wasn;'t shouting ... when I wrote the message, I originally tried to distinguish code by using lower case not realizing it would be reformatted ...

Thank you, that worked!! Still need to understand what I can and cannot in terms of column/variable manipulation using a loop; can you direct me to a relevant source?

Try:
data[data==9999] <- NA
